# Send email through Google Workspace with Oauth

Tags: civimail, smtp, google, oauth

### Summary

Is Oauth authentication method supported to use Google as smtp server for outbound Civimail ?
With recent Google announcement, I fear our Civimail setup will be broken in September 2024

### Detailed reasons for the question

1. As per this [google announcement](https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2023/09/winding-down-google-sync-and-less-secure-apps-support.html), starting next June 2024, Oauth method will be mandatory to use Google as smtp server for Civicrm :

*Google Workspace will no longer support the sign-in method for third-party apps or devices that require users to share their Google username and password. This antiquated sign-in method, known as Less Secure Apps (LSAs), puts users at an additional risk since it requires sharing Google Account credentials with third-party apps and devices that can make it easier for bad actors to gain unauthorized access to your account. Instead, you’ll need to use the option to Sign-In with Google [..]. Sign-in with Google leverages industry standard and more secure **OAuth** method of authentication*

2. We use our Google Workspace account as smtp relay in civicrm
3. We have Oauth client extension enabled. Demerit wrote [there](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/40265/is-there-a-way-to-have-civicrm-send-receive-mail-using-the-wp-mail-smtp-plugin) in August 2021 :
   *"In Civi at the current time OAUTH is only available for fetching mail/bounces, not sending mail"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the bottom of that article it says another alternative is https://support.google.com/mail/answer/185833. Oauth would be better, but you can use app passwords in the meantime.

Comment: Good answer, thanks a lot ! Will try this